# Are two logically equal indices physically the same index?

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, performance-tuning

I have a table with this definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public.delete_operation
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  parent_id bigint,
  pdu character varying,
  progress smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  description character varying,
  state character varying(31) NOT NULL,
  status character(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A'::bpchar,
  CONSTRAINT delete_operation_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "Ref_delete_operation_to_delete_operation" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
      REFERENCES public.delete_operation (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Index on id created implicitly.

Then I want to create an index on `parent_id` (which refers to same id column with already created index).

My question is: would it be physically same index with different names or will it double this index ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How can the 2 indexes be physically the same? The values of `id` could be more example:

```
1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9
```

while the `parent_id` values could be:

```
NULL,1,1,8,NULL,NULL,2,NULL
```

So the answer to the question is: No, they would be two completely separate and different structures. It doesn't make any other sense. Even if the `parent_id` were all, one by one, identical to the `id` values, it still would not make any sense either. Because the server cannot know or be sure that the values will be always identical. Rows can be updated and new rows with different id - parent_id values can be inserted. So two separate indexes have to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Even 2 same indices on same column would be 2 different physical indices.
You can check the index file name with :

```
select relfilenode, relname from pg_class where relname = 'index_name';
```

Correlate the physical files in :

```
~PGDATA/base/db_oid/relfilenode
```